# Setting a greeting with PHP based on date/time

Tags: php

I have the following code which I am using to get a greeting to display to the user based on what the time is. The print out I get is 'Good Morning,00 the date and time now is xx/xx/xx xx:xx'. The problem is obviously the 00 after the greeting. What have I done wrong?

```
<?php 
    $hour = date("H");
    if ($hour <= '11' ) {
        echo 'Good Morning,';
    }

    else {
        echo 'Good Afternoon,';
    };

    echo $hour . ' the date and time now is  ' . date('d/m/y H:i');
?>
```

Comment: Really?  Did you even look at the code?

Comment: Yes. I've just started out with PHP and coding in general so was looking for a bit of advice. But thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If so pick an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the "$hour ." in the echo.

The code should be,

```
echo ' the date and time now is ' . date('d/m/y H:i');
```

Note you also had an extra space after the "is" that probably wasn't intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on the last line of code:

echo $hour is causing it. Your code should be

```
echo 'the date and time now is  ' . date('d/m/y H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $hour . ' the date and time now is  ' . date('d/m/y H:i');
```

should be just:

```
echo ' the date and time now is  ' . date('d/m/y H:i');
```